# Question about Emerging Market index - EEM ETF

Tags: etf, emerging-markets

I read that the EEM ETF replicates the Emerging Market index.  Which leads me to ask, is there an official Emerging Market index? Or what exactly does it replicate?

I've found the following index: https://www.investing.com/indices/msci-emerging-markets

I am a bit confused because per my understanding, there is no official Emerging Market Index? Hope someone can clarify.

Answer (score 2):

MCSI is an organization like Standard & Poors (S&P).  The MCSI Emerging Markets index is some index that MCSI keeps using some indexing methodology.

Separately there are funds that seek to track the performance of the MCSI Emerging Markets index.  Once such example is iShares MSCI Emerging Markets ETF, ticker EEM, linked [here](https://www.investing.com/etfs/ishares-msci-emg-markets).

[This is the MCSI page that explains the Emerging Markets index.](https://www.msci.com/emerging-markets)